# Integrate wordpress blog with joomla website

Tags: wordpress, joomla, blogs

I have a website which I developed  in joomla and a blog in wordpress. I would like to integrate that blog with my Joomla website without using wrappers or CorePHP component.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can hope for in this situation is going to be to have one be a subdomain of the other, and when you want one system to reference the other you'll need to link to it.  Also, if you could move one of the systems to be a subfolder of the other system, you'll probably get away with having relative links.

The only other option would be to literally migrate all of your content from one system to the other manually.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a feed reader in your Joomla website to show your Wordpress posts?